# How do I get a reference to an anonymous module?

Tags: angularjs

If my app is defined as so...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app>
```

How do I get a reference to the module so I can access the directive?

I can't do this...

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive
```

.. because the app doesn't have a name.

Comment: What are you planning on using from the `ng-app`?  You always have access to its scope through `$rootScope`.

Comment: I want to add a directive.

Answer (score 3):

It is other way around. You first define your module in JavaScript and then you have to reference a top-level module from the `ng-app` attribute:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: I don't want to change the name of the app though in case it breaks anything.

Comment: ? Could you elaborate on "in case it breaks anything."?

Comment: The html element is in a page template and other pages that use the template may break if I change the name of the app.

Comment: All that you need to ensure is that your application has only one occurrence of the `ng-app` directive - changing the name assigned to it will not break your app. Just ensure that the name is updated anywhere that is used in `angular.module()`

Answer (score 1):

You can also manually bootstrap your app by calling the following:

```
   angular.element(document).ready(function() {
     angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
   });
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest way to satisfy the particular requirements of the original question. (Although naming the app properly is probably cleaner when building everything from scratch.)